# php preg_split with regex, need a trick?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Here is my string:

```
$myString = "first second third,el forth, fiveeee, six";
```

What I want to capture is:

```
first
second
third
el forth
fiveeee
six
```

This is what I tried for regex to be used in preg_split:

```
 $myPattern = "[\s,]";
```

The problem is this captures "el" and "forth" seperatly..

How can I trick this into capturing el forth?

Edit:

I was not clear..
I want to capture el forth as a single array element.. Because EL is too short.. I think it as a single word. Like:

`EL CLASSICO,SOMETHING DIFFERENT,SOMETHINGELSEHERE SOMEMORETEXT` should be:

```
* `EL CLASSICO`
* `SOMETHING DIFFERENT`
* `SOMETHINGELSEHERE`
* `SOMEMORETEXT`
```

They should be seperated by spaces OR commas but if there is something like EL or LE, that should be ignored.

Comment: How do you determine if a string like "el forth" should be captured as one item vs. "first second" being captured as two items?  What I am getting at is that as it currently stands, without the programmer having an idea as to what the actual string is, you have no way of reliably splitting up such a string when the values in the string change.

Comment: @MikeBrant I want to decide if it is equal to or less than 3 characters like DER DIE DAS or EL or LE...

Comment: But "six" has three letters, so "six seven" would be captured as one.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it is ok if it has three letters. but it should not be captured if there is something like "xxx abcd", "xxx" at the end is fine since there is no more text after it. If there is, then it should be captures as whole.. It not, just get the tree letters. If there is a comma after 3 letters, get it as it is.. Too complicated I guess for regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$myString = "first second third,el forth,del fiveeee,six,six seven,four six";
$myPattern = "/\s*,\s*|(?<=[^\s,]{4})[\s,]+/";

print_r(preg_split($myPattern, $myString));
?>
```

produces

```
[0] => first
[1] => second
[2] => third
[3] => el forth
[4] => del fiveeee
[5] => six
[6] => six seven
[7] => four
[8] => six
```

`(?<=[^\s,]{4})` is a [positive look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It is only successful if preceded by four non-separator characters (but it does not match the characters themselves, it only checks that they exist). This allows it not to split if the previous word was too short.
But it will always split if the separator includes a comma -- that's what `\s*,\s*|` is for.

Comment: Thanks perfect. I guess I will need an hour to understand this.. Hopefully. Maybe a day.. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the positive look-behind assertion in parenthesis?

Comment: Instead of: \s*,\s*| why is a simple ,| not enough, if this is only for splitting by commas?

Comment: Regular expressions use parenthesis to group sub-expressions. So you can say, for example, `(ab)*` to match `ab` or `abab` or `ababab` (and so on) but not `abb` or `aba`. In this case, the `?<=` at the beginning of the subexpression means treat this subexpression as a positive look-behind.

Comment: As for `\s*,\s*|`, it also allows the comma to have whitespace around it. This allows `six, six , six` to work the same as `six,six,six`.

Answer (score 2):

**not good solution after question edit, igrone**

just `str_replace( ',' , ' ' , $myString)` eventually `str_replace( '  ', ' ' , $myString)` to avoid double spaces or:

`preg_replace( '@, ?' , ' ' , $myString)`

Answer (score 0):

```
implode(' ', preg_split('/,\s*/', $myString));
```